# How can I create a clickable button in graphics.py window?

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

I'm trying to make a game, and have the start screen have a button that you can click to start playing the game.

I tried the `clickPoint=getMouse()` but I am unsure how to incorporate it. Can I use the `while True` statement or would I have to use something else?

Comment: first you could show in question (not in comments) minimal working code - so we could see what you really do.

Comment: `zella graphics` is different than all other GUI frameworks and I think you will have to use `clickPoint = getMouse()` inside `while True:` and check if you clicked in correct place.

Comment: theoretically `zella graphics` is created using `tkinter` which has `tkinter.Button(..., command=function)` but `zella graphics` works different than `tkinter` and it can make problem to use `tkinter.Button()` directly with `Graphics`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically `zella graphics` is created using `tkinter` which has `tkinter.Button(..., command=function)` but `zella graphics` works different than `tkinter` and it can make problem to use `tkinter.Button()` directly with `zella graphics`.

At this moment the only idea is to use `while True` with `getMouse()` (or `checkMouse()`) and check if you clicked inside button's rectangle.

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("My Buttons", 200, 200)

c = Rectangle(Point(50,50), Point(150,100))
c.setFill('Red')
c.draw(win)

while True:
    clickPoint = win.getMouse()
    
    if (c.getP1().getX() <= clickPoint.getX() <= c.getP2().getX()
        and c.getP1().getY() <= clickPoint.getY() <= c.getP2().getY()):
            print('Red Button Clicked')
            break

win.close()
```

---

If you have many buttons then you could create new class `Button` (using `Rectangle) with function which checks if it was clicked.

```
class Button(Rectangle):

    def isClicked(self, point):
        return (self.getP1().getX() <= point.getX() <= self.getP2().getX()
                and self.getP1().getY() <= point.getY() <= self.getP2().getY())
```

or shorter

```
class Button(Rectangle):

    def isClicked(self, point):
        return (self.p1.x <= point.x <= self.p2.x
                and self.p1.y <= point.y <= self.p2.y)
```

and now `if` needs shorter code

```
from graphics import *

class Button(Rectangle):

    def isClicked(self, point):
        #return (self.getP1().getX() <= point.getX()<= self.getP2().getX()
        #        and self.getP1().getY() <= point.getY() <= self.getP2().getY()
    
        return (self.p1.x <= point.x <= self.p2.x
                and self.p1.y <= point.y <= self.p2.y)
      
# --- main ---
        
win = GraphWin("My Buttons", 200, 200)

c = Button(Point(50,50), Point(150,100))
c.setFill('Red')
c.draw(win)

d = Button(Point(50,100), Point(150,150))
d.setFill('Green')
d.draw(win)

while True:
    clickPoint = win.getMouse()
    
    if c.isClicked(clickPoint):
       print('Red Button Clicked')
       break

    if d.isClicked(clickPoint):
       print('Green Button Clicked')
       break

win.close()
```